Multilabel classification in pytorch, how to represent ground truth and which loss function to use?
I am working on a project in which I have to perform a classification with a neural network. I am using a simple MLP, starting with 1024 features. So I have a 1024-dimensional array with one or two numbers associated with it.
These numbers are (in this case), integers, that are limited in the range [0, 359]. What is the best way to train a model to learn this? My first idea is to use a vector as ground truth in which all elements are 0 but the labels. The problem is that I do not know what kind of loss function I can use to optimize this model. Moreover, I do not know if it is a problem that the number of labels is not fixed.
I also have another question. This kind of representation may be working for this case but it is not working for other types of data. Since it is possible that the labels I am using may not be integers anymore in later project stages (but more complex data such as multiple floating point values), is there any way to represent them in a way that makes sense for more than one type of data?

Stack Overflow is a site for getting support on coding issues.  Your question is better suited for the stats stackexchange.
